# Freebase API - listing a city's tourist attractions by relevance

Tags: api, search, location, coordinates, freebase

I'm trying to use Freebase to list tourist attractions for cities by relevance.

Using the Topic API, it's simple to retrieve results for a certain city using its MID (e.g. "/m/04jpl" for London)

**https:// www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/topic/m/04jpl/?&filter=/travel/travel_destination/tourist_attractions**

However, this gives a limited 10 results. The response ends with `"count": 87.0"`. How do I get all 87? It's possible to click a "87 values total" link on London's Freebase page. Effectively, I want to do the same here.

I realise I could use MQL, but I want the results to be ranked by relevance, not by timestamp. Using the Search API, it's possible to rank by freebase, entity or schema, so I'd rather use that.

First, I looked at the Search Output schema for the Search API. However, even outputting "all" didn't produce Tourist Attraction results. Using metaschema with the Search API DID work. I used "part_of" to select London. However, it only works for some locations:

**https:// www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search?limit=50&filter=(all%20type:/travel/tourist_attraction%20part_of:/m/04jpl)&indent=true**

What I REALLY want to be able to do is make it work for a relatively unknown location like "[Loughborough](http://www.freebase.com/m/01z21p)" (MID /m/01z21p). As you can see, substituting /m/04jpl for /m/01z21p produces no results:

**https:// www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search?limit=50&filter=(all%20type:/travel/tourist_attraction%20part_of:/m/01z21p)&indent=true**

Looking at "Loughborough", we see that its tourist attraction like "[Loughborough Town Hall](http://www.freebase.com/m/0f9zzl)" has a "/travel/tourist_attraction/near_travel_destination" of "Loughborough". How would I compose this filter?

I want something like the following (that actually works):

**https:// www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search?limit=50&filter=(all%20type:/travel/tourist_attraction)&filter=(/travel/tourist_attraction/near_travel_destination:/m/01z21p)&indent=true**

Thanks!

NOTE: To enter the links into your browser you need to remove the space between the https:// and www. I would have done so, but I don't have the required permissions here yet to post more than 2 links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem using 2 Freebase API calls.

1) An MQL query that gets a list of all the tourist attractions for a particular MID. These results are not ranked in any useful way. I am also returning the result number to make processing a little easier later

```
https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/mqlread?query={"mid":"/m/04jpl","/travel/travel_destination/tourist_attractions":[{"mid":null}],"resultnumber:/travel/travel_destination/tourist_attractions":[{"return":"count"}]}
```

The list of returned MIDs are then used to create a new query (using a for loop). You must enter all MIDs returned from the above query, so that they can all be ranked together.

2) `https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search?limit=10&filter=(any%20mid:/m/0gsxw%20mid:/m/01d_0p%20mid:/m/07gyc)&scoring=entity`

It's best to choose a return format that just returns MIDs, to ensure that loading times aren't extensive.

You then have a ranked list of MIDs! You'll need one final query to return whatever details you desire.

I hope this has proved helpful.